# Pattern matching with half defined generics

Tags: c#

Consider this method signature. It should return the field value of a record. The field name and the record itself are provided as input.

```
object GetValue<TRecord>(TRecord record, string fieldName);
```

or (it's the same for my purposes)

```
object GetValue(object record, string fieldName);
```

The record could be anything. It could be a POCO class instance. It could be a `DataRow` instance, it could be a `IDataRecord`, it could be an `IDictionary` or it could be an `IDictionary<string,[someType]>`

I use pattern matching with types like this (code is simplified)

```
switch(record)
{
   case DataRow row: return row[fieldName];
   case IDataRecord rec: return rec[fieldName];
   case IDictionary dict: return dict[fieldName];
   default: // assume poco class. Use reflection.
     return record.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(record);
}
```

I miss the matching with `IDictionary<string, ...>`. Can I use the code below?

```
case IDictionary<string, T> gDict: return gDict[fieldName];
```

or do I have to fall back to reflection techniques too? Would the pattern matching system recognise the `T` type as a placeholder for whatever type there is?

Comment: I think just `c#` tag is enough.

Comment: Must admit, I'm not a fan of using pattern matching like this, I'd rather see multiple overloads.

Comment: if you changed your method signature to `T GetValue<T>(object record, string fieldName)` you could actually do this.

Comment: Probably https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/154.

Comment: Using a `switch` like that is awful. I feel like there's a strongly-typed way to do what you want, but you've only given us part of what you're really trying to do. Can you tell us how this code fits in to the bigger picture of your program?

Comment: @Jacek that won't work. My problem is not the return type (which I don't even know at compile time, so I leave it as object). My problem is to determine what kind of record object I have and retrieve the desired value from it given a field name.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is an excel exporter that uses a third party library to create the excel file. I want to fill each sheet with data, so I iterate on each record of my input first, then on each field of that record and I retrieve the value and feed it to the third party lib. I want to be able to export `DataTables`, `IDataReaders`, `IDictionaries` and POCO classes. The `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation does not implement `IDictionary`, which would be convenient. My question may be misleading. My problem is not pattern matching itself but how to avoid reflection.

Comment: Would `case IDictionary<string, object>...` work ?

Comment: @cmos That would not work, since an IDictionary<string, int> (for example) is not castable to an IDictionary<string, object>